# update current row based on values of next row

Tags: pandas, python-3.5, pandas-groupby

I have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['1','1','1','1','2','2','2'], \
                   'episode': ['111', '112','113', '114','115','116','117'], \
                   'risk': ['L', 'L','H', 'L','H','L','L'], \
                   'date': ['21-01-2015', '27-02-2015','19-03-2015', '09-05-2015','3-01-2015','7-02-2015','11-05-2015']})
```

There can be few rows (different episode number) in every ID and every row has a risk identification as L or H. I want to check if for every ID, there exist a risk H. Once there is a risk H present in any episode of an ID, I want to change the risk in the remaining rows to H so that any preceding episodes of the same ID should have risk H. The data is already sorted by ID, episode and date. Final output will be:

```
  ID       date episode risk
0  1 2015-01-21     111    L
1  1 2015-02-27     112    L
2  1 2015-03-19     113    H
3  1 2015-05-09     114    H
4  2 2015-01-03     115    H
5  2 2015-02-07     116    H
6  2 2015-05-11     117    H
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check with `groupby` + `cumprod`

```
df['risk'].ne('H').groupby(df['ID']).cumprod().map({True:'L',False:'H'})
Out[265]: 
0    L
1    L
2    H
3    H
4    H
5    H
6    H
Name: risk, dtype: object
#df['risk']=    df['risk'].ne('H').groupby(df['ID']).cumprod().map({True:'L',False:'H'})
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know this cumprod function before.